# Execute multiple build files using ant

Tags: build, ant

I have different projects and each project on a folder and each project have a unique build.xml file.

example
There is a main folder and under that 3 different folders called A,B and C.
inside each A,B and C folders there is a unique build.xml file.

Are there any way to execute all these 3 build.xml files from apache ant  by using a common build.xml?
If possible how to do that?

Comment: If the answer below solved your issue, please mark it and/or vote it up! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic purpose of the `<ant>` task. The manual page contains many examples and options: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

E.g.

```
<target name="build-subprojects">
   <ant antfile="subproject1/build.xml"/>
   <ant antfile="subproject2/build.xml"/>
</target>
```